# Android menu item single share button

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock, menuitem, shareactionprovider

I'm trying to add a share button in my Action Bar Sherlock.

**BUT**

I don't want to have the second share button to appear next to it like that [image]

How can i achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

Implement OnShareTargetSelectedListener and set it on the ShareActionProvider

**Here is the code:**

```
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    ....
    actionProvider.setOnShareTargetSelectedListener(this);
    ....


 @Override 
 public boolean onShareTargetSelected(ShareActionProvider source, 
         Intent intent) { 

     context.startActivity(intent); 

     // started activity ourself to prevent search history 
     return true; 
 }
```

Comment: For now it is half working : the second item doesn't how up, but the share item is not immediatly clickable :/ i must change activity for it to become clickable